# codeigniter variable as variable using Different Method

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

```
$i = 2;

$this->variable2 = "test"; // $this->variable2 is defined

$this->variable= '$this->variable'.$i;

echo ${$this->variable};
```

Error

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined variable: $this->variable2

Comment: "how to use and update $$var all function with in controller ?" <- can you rephase this please? Also, using variable variables is generally considered bad practice. Use arrays instead (or objects).

Comment: Please give more inputs to understand your aim

Comment: Please show a code example that illustrates how you're trying to share the variable within a controller.

Comment: That answer is how to use var in class and function

Comment: this question is how to pass var as var

Comment: if one to ten var easily pass via function

Comment: in my case i have thousands of $var as  $var

Comment: can i type every $var this is very very ...................bad idea

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**This Method Using Different Type of uses.**

Finaly i found the solution

Create Variable in one Function method

Update Variable in Another Function method

Call Variable in Different Function methods

But never call Variable name Directly!!!.

```
public function BWT_start($i){
    global $varx;
    
    $varx = 'var'.$i;
    
    return $varx;
}

// Call Global Variable With Different Method with Never call Variable name Directly!!!.
public function BWT_run(){
    
    global $varx;
    
    for($i=1;$i<=7;$i++){
        $this->BWT_start($i); //echo Show created Variable Name

        $this->BWT_update($i); //echo Show updated Variable value
        
        $this->BWT_process($i); //echo Show Again Changed Variable value
    }
}

public function BWT_update($i){
    global $varx; global $$varx;
    
    $$varx = "DB_ROW_$i<br>";

    return $$varx;
    // 
}

public function BWT_process($i){
    $vary = 'var'.$i;
    global $$vary;
    $$vary = "DB_UPDATE_$i<br>";
    return $$vary;
}
```